# DateTime function to foreach

Tags: php, datetime

I have a simple code here that converts the `DateTime` format to `Y-m-d`. Here is my code:

```
$var = '2015-11-06';

$images = $db->query("SELECT * FROM images");

foreach ($images as $i) {
  $created_at = $i['created_at'];
}

$date = new DateTime($created_at);
$newDate = $formattedDate->format('Y-m-d');
```

The dates in my database is formatted like this (`2015-11-06 03:07:15`).

What I wanted to do is to get all the values equal to `$var` in the `$newDate` and to use `foreach` to echo out all the equal values. How can I possibly do that?

Comment: No idea what you're trying to do. `$newDate` isn't an array, it's just one date.

Comment: Since you're calling `new DateTime($created_at)` outside the loop, you're just using the creation time of the last image. You might as well just write `$created_at = $images[count($images)-1]['created_at'];`.

Comment: Your date format will never be equal to `$var`, because you're formatting with `-` separators, but `$var` has `/` separators.

Comment: Why not search the db based on the date

Comment: How can I search from db if the format has time? @Dagon

Comment: Insert the `$date` and `$newDate` inside your foreach

Comment: What happened to the original code in the question? Now it's the same as my answer, which makes no sense!

Comment: You can search the database with: `WHERE DATE(created_at) == '$var'`

Comment: Don't change the question to match the answer. How is someone reading this question suppose to understand what the problem was, so they can see how I helped you?

Comment: Ok, sorry for that @Barmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you're asking, but maybe this is it. You have to do the formatting inside the loop.

```
foreach ($images as $i) {
    $date = new DateTime($i['created_at']);
    $dateFormatted = $date->format('Y-m-d');
    if ($dateFormatted == $var) {
        echo $dateFormatted;
    }
}
```

You could also do it in the database query:

```
$images = $db->query("SELECT * FROM images 
                    WHERE created_at BETWEEN '$var 00:00:00' AND '$var 23:59:59'");
```

Comment: It's not a trick, it's just a straightforward translation of what you want into code.

Answer (score -1):

Use strtotime to convert the dates to unix timestamp and compare that.